# Adding a column with no header to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I add an empty column to my dataframe without introducing a header to it?

I am using pandas to work on a dataframe where I need to add an empty column without any header. I know that by using

```
df["New_Column_Name"] = ""
```

(where df is my dataframe) would add an empty column to the df. But, in my case I don't want that "New_Column_Name" there.
Thanks.

Comment: Why'd you want to something like that? Can't imagine a usecase where that helps. But if you really need it, what about `df[''] = ''`. Checking `df.columns` after that shows, that a new column has been created.

Comment: I wanted to separate two different blocks of calculations by an empty column. df['']='' indeed worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {'Name': ['Rob', 'Bob', 'Tob'],
        'Age': [20, 21, 19]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[''] = ''
print(df.columns)
```

output:

```
Index(['Name', 'Age', ''], dtype='object')
```